# java: as of release 10, 'var' is a restricted type name and cannot be used for type declarations or as the element type of an array

Tags: java

I keep getting this from jetbrains intellij
java: as of release 10, 'var' is a restricted type name and cannot be used for type declarations or as the element type of an array.

```
package com.ruse.world.content.collectionlog;

import com.ruse.model.definitions.NPCDrops;
import com.ruse.model.definitions.NpcDefinition;
import com.ruse.util.Misc;
import com.ruse.world.content.KillsTracker;
import com.ruse.world.content.TeleportInterface;
import com.ruse.world.entity.impl.player.Player;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.var;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

//import com.sun.scenario.effect.DropShadow;

 private void sendNpcData(int index) {
        int received = 0;
        int total = 0;
        var definition = NpcDefinition.forId(currentlyViewing.get(index));
        player.getPacketSender().resetItemsOnInterface(30375, 6 * 10);
        player.getPacketSender().sendString(30368, "" + definition.getName() + "");
        player.getPacketSender().sendString(30369, "Killcount: " +
                Misc.insertCommasToNumber(String.valueOf(KillsTracker.getTotalKillsForNpc(definition.getId(), player))));
        var drops = NPCDrops.forId(definition.getId());
        var slot = 0;
        if (drops != null && drops.getDropList() != null) {
            for (var npcDrop : drops.getDropList()) { //smaller and equal too means very common, and always,
                if (npcDrop.getChance() <= 1) {
                    continue;
                }
                if (hasObtainedItem(definition.getId(), npcDrop.getId())) {
                    var item = player.getCollectionLogData().stream().filter(data -> data.getNpcId() == definition.getId() && data.getItem() == npcDrop.getId()).findFirst().get();
                    player.getPacketSender().sendItemOnInterface(30375, item.getItem(), slot++, item.getAmount());
                    received++;
                } else {
                    player.getPacketSender().sendItemOnInterface(30375, npcDrop.getId(), slot++, 0);
                }
                total++;
            }
        }
        int lines = total / 6;
        if (total % 6 > 0)
            lines++;
        player.getPacketSender().setScrollMax(30385, lines * 40);
        player.getPacketSender().sendString(30367, "Obtained: @gre@" + received + "/" + total + "");
    }
```

Language level 8 - Lambdas, type annotations etc.

Trying to stop that error from showing up to build project

Comment: We need the full traceback …

Comment: what language is this? You don't declare variables with `int` in JavaScript.

Comment: What version of Java does your project use (for me it's File -> Project Structure -> Language Level)?

Comment: @TheEagle compiler errors don't have tracebacks.

Answer (score 0):

Language level 8 - Lambdas, type annotations etc will work only for Intellij and whenever you will try to build you application with any tool like gradle/maven with JDK 10, you will get this error as `var` is now reserved keyword in java 10 present in `java.lang` package.

Best solution is that remove below import line from your code and change Language level to 10, as you are already using java 10 so you don't need to use `var` from lombok library, jdk 10 itself will provide you `var` keyword, to automatically detect the datatype of a variable based on the surrounding context.

```
import lombok.var;
```

Comment: Correct, if you are using java 10 then you must use all features available in java 10 so Language level also must be set to 10.